# How to create a Thread in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8.1

**Hi**, I've tried to create a Thread in windows phone 8.1 without success.

Althought in msdn documentation is written that Thread is supported, actually do not works (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/274eh01d(v=vs.110).aspx)

so I can't figureout how can I create a Thread, I want to create a Syncronization context to execute async on a single thread (not current thread), but just to achieve what event loop do

thanks

#### update for further information:

I would be more specific:

platform is **universal app**, so I mean windows 8.1 & windows phone 8.1, no silverlight ecc.

I need to create a thread because I want to create a syncronization context to execute some async code, here is an example about what I mean http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx
the difference from this link is I would use a specific thread for all async code instead current thread.

thanks again

Comment: What exactly have you tried (I'd appreciate code, if you could, not just a link), and what makes you think it didn't work?

Comment: Have you tried the background worker? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Can you show us what you've attempted to do?

Comment: Keep in mind that WP81 can be either Silverlight or WinRT. The linked doc is for Silverlight. If you're building a WinRT phone app you cannot access this.

Comment: Careful that @ps2goat background workder is deprecated and no longer available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to run some code asynchronously, look into using [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx). It provides a much simpler mechanism than managing threads yourself.

If you are building an Universal Windows Phone 8.1 app, you can't use the .NET `Thread` type. If you need more control over the execution, you can use the WinRT [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpool.aspx).

Finally, if you really **really** need lots of control, there's always [`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want to write native code (this has recently been added to the allowed list of APIs for Store Apps, although MSDN isn't updated yet).

Comment: thanks for answer, but I can't figure out why microsoft removed the possibility to create thread

Comment: @LXG your background threads can run forever after shutting down the main process if you don't specify "IsBackground = true" on them.  I suppose they're just being secure as an incompetent developer could leave threads spinning endlessly in the background or a malicious one could spawn malicious threads that don't go away when you terminate the main process.