# Background thread in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app and I'm want to run a (potentially very long) while loop in the background. I've read several forum posts here and elsewhere, but none actually seem to resemble what I want to do. The idea is that I'm connected to a server using a `StreamSocket`, and the server sends an unknown number of GUIDs (could be 2, could be 1000). When the server sends a special one (for example, all zeroes), I want to break out of the while loop, but there may be other conditions that stop the while loop as well. Since good old `System.Threading.Thread` is not available, I'll need some other way to do this.

I've seen this post on SO: [How to create a Thread in windows phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508492/how-to-create-a-thread-in-windows-phone-8-1). This post links here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj248672.aspx. Under "Best practices" Microsoft say not to use `async/await` on anything that runs on the ThreadPool, which complicates things further.

I see two potential solutions:

- Use some other method to create a thread, with support of `async/await`
- Use the ThreadPool and use a blocking call to receive data from the server, without `async/await`

There could be some other way, but I've been at this for the entire day, so my brain is probably fried... thanks in advance though!

Comment: I *think* that using a while loop in that fashion will use a ton of resources.

Comment: Where do you see it talk about not using async/await with the thread pool? The only thing I see under the don't section is *"Don't try to create work item handlers that use the async keyword. This can cause unexpected behavior."* which is talking about using `async void` functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` to keep reading from an `IInputStream` without using an infinite loop:

```
private async void Foo()
{
    StreamSocket streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
    await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("localhost"), "8888");

    IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(16);
    IInputStream inputStream = streamSocket.InputStream;

    Task<IBuffer> readTask = inputStream.ReadAsync(
        buffer,
        buffer.Capacity,
        InputStreamOptions.None).AsTask();
    var notAwait = readTask.ContinueWith(ReadMore, streamSocket);
}

private void ReadMore(Task<IBuffer> task, object state)
{
    StreamSocket streamSocket = state as StreamSocket;

    if (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        // TODO: Handle error.
        return;
    }

    IBuffer buffer = task.Result;
    Guid guid = new Guid(buffer.ToArray());
    Debug.WriteLine(guid);

    if (guid == Guid.Empty)
    {
        // Close socket and stop reading.
        streamSocket.Dispose();

        return;
    }

    IInputStream inputStream = streamSocket.InputStream;

    Task<IBuffer> readTask = inputStream.ReadAsync(
        buffer,
        buffer.Capacity,
        InputStreamOptions.None).AsTask();
    var notAwait = readTask.ContinueWith(ReadMore, streamSocket);
}
```

Comment: Every guid should be 16 bytes. What symptoms do you see?

Comment: Can you share some NETMON traces? You can capture the traces on the server side.